# Special Cells with Specific Format

Tags: excel, vba

In a range of 10 cells  i have 2 cells of red colors.

Like I can identify the blank cells using below

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

rng.Select
```

Is there a way to identify cells of specific format (in this case cells with Red color)

as specialcells does not show any relevant option.

I want to identify these red cells in a range preferably without any loop.

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330345/vba-to-identify-cells-in-red)

Comment: @mehow Is it really ?

Comment: Y downward????...Kindly read my question properly....

Comment: @Santosh dont you recon?

Comment: @mehow  I dont think so :)

Comment: @user2230817 Without loop i dont think so its possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done without looping through the range.  Any reason you can't / don't want to loop?  With a range that small (even a range 10x that), if done properly, won't take any noticeable time.

Comment: even calling an excel built in function the looping exist - it just happens behind the scenes - but it loops

Comment: @mehow as in this case `Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` behind the scenes loop will be called and OP wants that. Why dont you read the question?

Comment: @Santosh because what hes asking for doesnt exist thats why its a duplicate

Comment: you can do it in two steps but still involves looping. Find what you want save it as string then select range from a string like `Array("row:row","row2:row2")` to have just the selection done in one go

Comment: @mehow if something doesnot exist you will downvote and mark it as duplicate ? Does that make any sense? I believe even OP is aware of the issue and wants any alternative solutions from this forum.

Comment: @mehow, the OP isn't asking how to prevent Excel doing a behind the scenes loop in the background memory, he is asking if it's possible to do what he wants without looping in VBA ...

Answer (score 0):

altering a color in a cell is **non-volatile** - that means that cells depending on the color will not be updated if their reference cell changes.

Having said that, and also having recommended against using the color to make a decision (when you should try to use the value) you could try the below:

1. see [Using old XLM GET.CELL (function 63) function to reference color](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/744559-cell-function-detecting-color-format.html?p=2377147&viewfull=1)
2. use that function to create an `#NA` value in the cell (so `=IF(...,NA(),"")` maybe?
3. Use SpecialCells to return the cells with `#NA` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba) for some tips)

I hope that gets you started, at least with some reading that might point you in the right direction.

But **again, you should try to make your decision based on a cells value, not formatting**