# Conditional Formula issue on excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell labeled "Total Balance" and then on my weekly payments I have the amount to be paid. Usually I pay the item and then change the color yellow. Is there a formula that I can use to automatically deduct from the Total Balance when the item's cell turns yellow for when I paid it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it only via color you need macro as there is no formula that can detect format. 
Example: [VBA to identify cells in red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330345/vba-to-identify-cells-in-red)

Comment: While there could be a UDF, that detect a specific format though. However this still ends up using a macro.