# Function to count conditionally formatted coloured cells

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro which counts conditionally formatted coloured cells.

```
'Variable declaration
Dim lColorCounter2 As Long
Dim rngCell2 As Range
'loop throughout each cell in the range
For Each rngCell2 In Selection
    'Checking Amber color
    If Cells(rngCell2.Row, rngCell2.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
        lColorCounter2 = lColorCounter2 + 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Green =" & lColorCounter2
```

I am trying to change it into a function. I've read on here that it may be because `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` doesn't work for functions. Is there a workaround?

Ideally I would like the function to have two arguments, the range of cells to search in for the colours and the second a cell with the colour to look for.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to rethink the entire approach. You'd be better off with formulas that test the conditions used for the conditional formatting.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366145/vba-function-to-test-if-cell-is-conditionally-formatted-in-excel .  Chris' answer is pretty solid response to what can work, though the comments to the main post hold what i feel is the mos tvaluable info.

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330345/vba-to-identify-cells-in-red

Comment: Why are you writing it like `Cells(rngCell2.Row, rngCell2.Column)`? Just do `rngCell2.DisplayFormat...`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that:

1. RGB(255, 192, 0) is not green but close to orange.
2. Change the range you want to loop - rng (now rng equals to **Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")**)

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Color(ByVal rng As Range)

    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In rng
        'Checking Amber color
        If Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Orange=" & Counter

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")

    Call Color(rng)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone but unfortunately these solutions won't work for me. I have around 25 different arrays of cells with many different conditional formatting conditions applied that I need to count the resulting colours of every month, so this would only really work as a function where I can input the respective cell array