# HowTo show Immediate Window in Worksheet

Tags: excel

in a [respons to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330345/vba-to-identify-cells-in-red) on this site an autor placed a screenshot of a Worksheet, with a Immediate Window **in** the worksheet. When I use the same code, I only get the immediate (or Debug.print) in the VBA editor.

Why do I not get the same result as in the sample?

Thanks for helping out !!

SoftAid

Comment: You can just drag the immediate window over to the worksheet.

Comment: If you want a more involved solution you can do something like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/192810 and create a logger that displays the messages in a modeless UserForm (that's how I do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab the window and drag it over, this should work in every MS Office product.

[image: Dragging the Immediate Window]